# The correct way to add a context menu to QGraphicsItem?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am working on an editor written in PyQt, and I would like to be able to open context menus connected to my `QGraphicsItem`:s in my `QGraphicsScene`. I have searched for solutions for using context menus in conjunction with the graphics-items, and have found a solution that opens a working context-menu which triggers actions from the items. A minimal working example below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class TestItem(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, scene=None):
        super(TestItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsMovable | self.ItemIsSelectable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(0,0,50,50)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget=None):
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        testAction = QtGui.QAction('Test', None)
        testAction.triggered.connect(self.print_out)
        menu.addAction(testAction)
        menu.exec_(event.screenPos())

    def print_out(self):
        print 'Triggered'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QWidget()
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()

    item = TestItem(scene=scene)
    view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)

    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(view)
    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is that sometimes after the context menu has been opened, the item's position is shifted when it is moved in the scene. Sometimes the shift is quite large which is very annoying and gives a very buggy appearance to the editor. And I haven't been able to track down the cause of the problem.

Is there perhaps a better way to use context menus in a `QGraphicsScene` which doesn't give rise to this behaviour? I would like to be able to open menus depending which type of item is clicked and figured that this could be a neat solution.